# Laravel Seeder using Factory Faker having Relation of Relation

Tags: laravel-8, faker, laravel-seeding

Below are the Tables with fiddle [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/aZbqKBMF)

#### TableA

| id | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |

#### TableB

| id | tableA_id | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 10 |

#### TableC

| id | tableB_id | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 1 | 5 |

I have a three table with relation of each other.

```
TableA->TableB->TableC
              ->TableC
```

`count` column in TableB->count is sum of TableC->quantity relation.

How Can I seed the tables using a Laravel Factory Faker?

What I have tried?

TableASeeder

#### Method:1

```php
public function run()

 $qty = fake()->randomElement([100, 150,200,250,300,400]);
        $tbla = TableA::factory()->has(TableB::factory()->count(2)->state([
            'count' => $qty,
        ])
        ->has(TableC::factory()->count(2)->state([
            'quantity' => round($qty/2),
        ])))->create();}
```

Method:1 code I am getting below error message

```
Call to undefined method App\Models\TableB::tableb()
```

#### Method:2

```php
public function run()
 $event = TableA::factory()
        ->afterCreating(function ($tba) use($qty) {
             
            TableB::factory()->for($tba)->state([
                'count' => $qty,
            ])->afterCreating(function($tbb) use($qty){
                TableC::factory()->for($tbb)->state([
                    'quantity' => round($qty/2),
                ])->count(2)->create();
            })->count(2)->create();
        })->create();
```

Method:2 code I am getting below error message

```
Call to undefined method 6Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne::getOwnerKeyName()
```

When I run the above seeder `TableASeeder` it creates a `TableA` Record and Two `TableB` Records

Now I need to seed `TableC` which is two records each with quantity sum equal to `TableB->count` in the above case it should be 10.